# How to display the json's Mutable Array data like Expandable/Collapsible TableView in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, ios7

I am new to IOS. I am getting the data from WebService and stored that data into MutableArrays using json serialization. But now i have to display that data in TableView like Expandable and Collapsible Cells. Please send me the sample code to solve this problem.

```
  NSMutableArray *arr=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString *Str_Menu_desc=[NSString alloc]init];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/CategoryInfo.php"];

    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *err;

    json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&err];


    NSEnumerator *enu=[json objectEnumerator];

    while (dic =(NSDictionary *)[enu nextObject])
    {

            [arr addObject:[dic1 objectForKey:@"menu_name"]];

    }


    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

{

    return [arr count];

}


    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;


{

    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
    cell.textLabel.text=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;


}


    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

{

    NSString *local=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


       NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/SubCategoryInfo.php"];

    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSError *err;

    json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&err];


    NSEnumerator *enu=[json objectEnumerator];

    while (dic =(NSDictionary *)[enu nextObject])
    {
        if (local isEqual:[dic objectForKey:@"category_name"]])
        {

            Str_Menu_desc=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dic objectForKey:@"Sub_Category_name"]];

        }
    }



}
```

Now, i got SubCategory Names using selected Category Name. I have to display Category and Subcategory Names in Expandable/Collapsible TableView. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by expandable-collapsible cells? May be it something like this: [Expanding/Collapsing TableView Sections](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/)?

In another way data, received in -tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method, put in new UITableViewController and push it controller in views hierarchy with line of code like this: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:content animated:YES];` Remember: navigationController must be created first, otherwise code will be non-working.